# Insert csv values into MySQL database using Column Name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I download a data feed that supplies property listings for Real Estate Websites.  I am converting this feed into csv files, and I have a couple of php files that insert csv data into a mysql database.  I have them working based off of the array number (ie '".$mq_out($arr[1])."' and so on.  The problem is, I do not control this feed myself, so the array numbers change often, when any updates are made to this feed.  These updates are happening frequently, so I am trying to avoid having to reconfigure the arrays every time.

Is there a way to import the array data based off of the column name in the csv file?

Here is a sample of my sql insert script and my csv file.

```
$sql = "insert into ".$tablename." values (
 '',
 '',
 '".mq_out($arr[9])."',
 '".mq_out($arr[5])."',
 '".mq_out($arr[7])."' ,
 '".mq_out($arr[13])."' ,
 '".mq_out($arr[14])."'  ,
 '' ,
 '".mq_out($arr[U_UserLastName])."',
 '".mq_out(.$row->U_LoginName.)."',
 '".mq_out($arr[2])."',
 '".mq_out($arr[4])."',
 '".mq_out($arr[6])."',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '".mq_out($arr[14])." ".mq_out($arr[15])."',
 '',
 '',
 '')";
```

The csv file is here.  http://stevenwilsondesigns.com/samplecsv.html

Comment: I tried adding the '".mq_out($arr[U_UserLastName])."',
 '".mq_out(.$row->U_LoginName.)."', to the file, but those did not work.

Comment: What type of feed is it? Are the columns always constant? What is mq_out?

Comment: Add code which determines the columns and modify your query based on that determination.